# Google Apps Script DriveApp.getFileById Stuck

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a project that requires finding the parent folder of a file. I've been trying to do this by using `DriveApp.getFileById().getParents()`. When it runs, however, it appears to get stuck in an infinite loop: the program never finishes and never produces an error. I've isolated the problem to the following lines:

```
var updtSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var newGen = DriveApp.getFileById(updtSS.getId());
```

The debugger gets stuck on the second line and just tries to run it over and over again, without ever advancing or actually executing it. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Is this a bug with Google Script?

*Edit*: It looks like it was a problem with the command itself, which Google has fixed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using `DriveApp.getFileById`. This started yesterday for me. We're not the only ones. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67054694

Answer (score 1):

In `script.google.com`:

1. Resources -> Advance Google Services
2. Enable Drive API
   [image]
3. You will be asked to enable it in the Google Dev console. Click the link and enable Drive API. Your script should run as intended now.